# Ruby app deployed successfully on GKE with gitlab runner but the migrations aren't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, deployment, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a containerized ruby app deployed to gcp gke cluster, everything works fine, infact, I can access the endpoint quite well, however, for some reason the db migration  and seed command is failing. I know it's failing because I get "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError".

My docker file looks like  ...

```
# Use a Ruby base image
FROM ruby:3.2.2

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files to the container
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install dependencies using bundler
RUN gem install bundler && \
    bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Run migrations
RUN rails db:migrate 

# Run the seeds
RUN rails db:seed


# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 for the Rails server
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Rails server
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and My deployment file looks like ..

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-ruby
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simple-ruby
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simple-ruby
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: simple-ruby
        image: registry.gitlab.com/hezronkimutai600/mpesa-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: simple-ruby-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    app: simple-ruby
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

I am getting the error below

[image]

Even though the issue is fixed when I click the "run pending migration button", I would like the migrations to be run automatically by the CI tool, how can I achieve that?

Here is my gitlab repo : https://gitlab.com/hezronkimutai600/mpesa-api

I added the migration and seed scripts in the dockerfile but still the problem persisted.